# Need TLS for GRPC network calls when running on host in Android Studio

Tags: android, ssl, grpc

I'm trying to do network calls over GRPC on a host machine (in a unit test in Android Studio), but the GRPC client cannot do TLS handshakes with the server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: We can not do TLS handshake on this Android version, please install the Google Play Services Dynamic Security Provider to use TLS
```

Is there a way to install a TLS provider on the Android Studio host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC-Java is recommending the use of [Play Service Dynamic Security Provider](https://www.appfoundry.be/blog/2014/11/18/Google-Play-Services-Dynamic-Security-Provider/) on Android. This ensures your application has an up-to-date OpenSSL library. See more information in [gRPC-Java SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.32.1/SECURITY.md).

Another option is to use [Conscrypt](https://conscrypt.org/), which you will insert the Conscrypt TLS provider before creating a gRPC channel.

```java
import org.conscrypt.Conscrypt;
import java.security.Security;
...

Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

Again, there are instructions in [gRPC-Java SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.32.1/SECURITY.md).

Using Conscrypt may be easier for tests, as it only requires the Conscrypt dependency.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me but with one note: for Android unit tests running on local machine, I had to use:    `implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:2.5.0'` per https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/649.